# New Line in PHP not working

Tags: php

Why Is my line break not working?

```
for($n=1; $n<=100; $n++)
{
    echo $n '\n';
}
?>
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I believe you have to concatenate `echo $n . '\n';` try that. And try using `"` instead of `'`.

Comment: Are you ouputting this to a web browser? It'll have to be `<br>` instead, since html doesn't obey standard `\n` line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new lines are ignored in HTML. Use `<br />` instead:

```
for($n=1; $n<=100; $n++)
{
    echo $n . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. You have syntax error there, it should be `$n . '\n'`
2. You are using `'` single quote to quote the new line (`\n`), thus it's being interpreted as literal `\` and `n`, change your code to: `$n . "\n"` to make it outputs as newline

Final code:

```
for($n = 1; $n <= 100; $n++)
{
    echo $n . "\n"; // or "$n\n" (thanks @ring0 for pointing that out)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dot (`.`) operator for string concatenation.

```
echo $n . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be in doule quotes:

```
Echo $n . "\n";
```

Comment: @bsdnoobz the alt key on my phone sometimes doesn't work as was the case here.

Answer (score 0):

First thing your concatination is wrong. It should be

```
echo $n ."\n";
```

Next thing, if you are using it to output in browser, you should use `<br />`

```
echo $n."<br />";
```

If you are writing it to files or console and you want to be platform independent, use `PHP_EOL`

```
echo $n.PHP_EOL
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, also remember that Newline characters are totally ignored in HTML (otherwise you'd have to do markup all on one line!)

If you're looking to get that effect, I'd recommend wrapping your output in nl2br, which converts your newlines into HTML breaks "
" so that they display properly.

```
nl2br($n . "\n");
```

or just

```
echo $n . "<br>";
```